I keep getting "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHEN'." Error in my SQL Query
My SQL query is as follows:
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#OutputIds') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #OutputIds;
CREATE TABLE #OutputIds (Action NVARCHAR(10), ChildId NVARCHAR(MAX));

MERGE INTO LeadShirts AS target
USING (VALUES ('abc', 'abc'), ('abc', 'abc')) AS source (ParentId, ChildId)
ON (target.Lead = source.ParentId AND target.Shirts = source.ChildId)
WHEN MATCHED AND target.Deleted = 1 THEN
    UPDATE SET UpdatedOn = GETDATE(), Deleted = 0  -- Re-activate deleted records
    OUTPUT 'Edited', source.ChildId INTO #OutputIds (Action, ChildId)
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
    INSERT (Lead, Shirts, Deleted, CreatedOn)
    VALUES (source.ParentId, source.ChildId, 0, GETDATE())
    OUTPUT 'Added', source.ChildId INTO #OutputIds (Action, ChildId);

INSERT INTO #OutputIds (Action, ChildId)
SELECT 'Skipped', ChildId
FROM (VALUES ('abc', 'abc'), ('abc', 'abc')) AS V(ParentId, ChildId)
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM LeadShirts AS T WHERE T.Lead = V.ParentId AND T.Shirts = V.ChildId AND T.Deleted IS NULL);

SELECT Action, ChildId FROM #OutputIds;

And I keep getting this error when I run it on SQL Server:

Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 11
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHEN'.

Any solution will be greatly appreciated.

You can only have one OUTPUT .. INTO clause and that goes in a specific place. Not one per action

ISO SQL's (VALUES( ... ) ) AS alias ( colA, colB ) syntax is awkward enough as-it-is, so using it inline within a MERGE statement is just inviting irritation... I suggest you move them out to either table-variables/temp-tables or a CTE.

@Dai - I disagree. It's use in MERGE is one of the least irritating places. If you move it into a CTE it becomes more irritating as you can't just use it directly as the definition for a CTE expression but need to add a SELECT from it

Postgres does allow using it directly here https://dbfiddle.uk/lSmUNsPz

As specified in the comment by @martin-smith, MERGE only has a single OUTPUT clause at the end of the expression: <output_clause>
The error you are experiencing is because SQL is confused, if OUTPUT only comes at the end, then what is the following WHEN keyword trying to do? The response from SQL is correct, incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHEN'
This should work instead, though you have less detail in your output:
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#OutputIds') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #OutputIds;
    
CREATE TABLE #OutputIds (Action NVARCHAR(10), ChildId NVARCHAR(MAX));

MERGE INTO LeadShirts AS target
USING (VALUES ('abc', 'abc'), ('abc', 'abc')) AS source (ParentId, ChildId)
    ON (target.Lead = source.ParentId AND target.Shirts = source.ChildId)
WHEN MATCHED AND target.Deleted = 1 THEN
    UPDATE SET UpdatedOn = GETDATE(), Deleted = 0  -- Re-activate deleted records
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
    INSERT (Lead, Shirts, Deleted, CreatedOn)
    VALUES (source.ParentId, source.ChildId, 0, GETDATE())
OUTPUT $action, source.ChildId INTO #OutputIds (Action, ChildId);

-- Change the action message for deleted
UPDATE #OutputIds
SET Action = 'Edited'
WHERE Action = 'DELETE';

-- Change the action message for inserted
UPDATE #OutputIds
SET Action = 'Added'
WHERE Action = 'INSERT';

INSERT INTO #OutputIds (Action, ChildId)
SELECT 'Skipped', ChildId FROM (VALUES ('abc', 'abc'), ('abc', 'abc')) AS V(ParentId, ChildId)
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM LeadShirts AS T WHERE T.Lead = V.ParentId AND T.Shirts = V.ChildId AND T.Deleted IS NULL);

SELECT Action, ChildId FROM #OutputIds;


I hope this helps explain out MERGE works and how you can still manipulate the output to meet your criteria if it is really that important ;)

Don't forget the obligatory MERGE HOLDLOCK ;)

@Dai that is good advice, though I'm reluctant to add it here, it's a bit off topic and I don't want to hang around to explain why it is useful and when you wouldn't use it. This chat should seed the idea though ;)

Seems preferable to use CASE $action WHEN 'UPDATE' THEN 'Edited' WHEN 'INSERT' THEN 'Added' END to get the desired string inserted directly rather than insert the undesired one and then update it

Absolutely if there are only a small number of changes to make, I would accept that PR ;) I was only demonstrating that it can be done, so went with a first principals approach. If OP is struggling with the documentation on MERGE I don't really want to introduce too many concepts
